# Django custom authentication implementation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to implement a custom authentication mechanism. I don't want to use the builtin mechanism. My scenario is as follows:

1- I am using the following model

```
class EndUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

2- I want to add users using the admin interface however I want to create a custom login form form where these created users can login

How will I implement this scenario. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Link to a full tutorial will be very helpfull

Comment: You **must not** do this. You can easily customise the built-in system to use your EndUser model, but you absolutely must not try and roll your own authentication, password management/validation, etc.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman for your response but can guide me how to customize the built-in system?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model